# Ansible - parsing a Json result with json_query

Tags: ansible, json-query

how are you doing ?

So, I am trying to extract two informations from a json. it is a response from API with all information about a specific server in a cloud plataform. So, with curl, I can show the raw data:

`curl --request GET --url "https://manage.runcloud.io/api/v2/servers/IDRANDOM/" -u apikey:apisecret --header 'accept: application/json' --header 'content-type: application/json'`

we will get this response:

`{"id":IDRANDOM,"name":"ServerName","provider":"OVH","ipAddress":"1.1.1.1","os":"Ubuntu","osVersion":"focal","connected":true,"online":true,"agentVersion":"2.5.8-1+ubuntu20.04+2","phpCLIVersion":"php74rc","softwareUpdate":true,"securityUpdate":true,"transferStatus":"AVAILABLE","created_at":"2018-06-26 19:24:53"}`

From that, I want to get two informations:

"ipAddress":"1.1.1.1"
"name":"ServerName"

These informations will update my ansible host file. So, it is important to get IP and Name.

So, using ansible, I've tried this code:

```
        - name: "Set header for access token key" 
          set_fact:
            batatas:
              Accept: application/json
              Content-Type: application/json


        - name: Server info
          uri:
            url: "https://manage.runcloud.io/api/v2/servers/{{ item }}"
            method: GET
            user: "{{ apikey }}"
            password: "{{ apisecret }}"
            force_basic_auth: yes # necessary to force authentication
            headers: "{{ batatas }}"
            body_format: json
          loop: "{{ id_servers }}"
          register: page

        - name: Debug Page
          debug:
            msg: "{{ page.results }}"

        - name: Show Name and IP
          debug:
             msg: "{{ page.results | json_query(info) }}"
          vars: 
             info: "page.results[*].{Name: name, IP: IpAddress}"
```

id_servers (Here, I replaced with IDRANDOM for security reasons) contains all the servers ID in runcloud API. So, I am using a loop to read the content and do a request to the runcloud API to get my information.

Running that, I am getting nothing:

```
Executing playbook get_info_server.yml

......

Debug Page...
  127.0.0.1 ok: {
    "changed": false,
    "msg": [
+++++ I've cutted some information  +++++++
        {
            "alt_svc": "h3=\":443\"; ma=86400, h3-29=\":443\"; ma=86400",
            "ansible_loop_var": "item",
            "cache_control": "no-cache, private",
            "cf_cache_status": "DYNAMIC",
            "cf_ray": "76e09a1cfdcd5d27-LIS",
            "changed": false,
            "connection": "close",
            "content_type": "application/json",
            "cookies": {},
            "cookies_string": "",
            "date": "Tue, 22 Nov 2022 09:22:41 GMT",
            "elapsed": 1,
            "failed": false,
            "invocation": {
                "module_args": {
                    "attributes": null,
                    "body": null,
                    "body_format": "json",
                    "ca_path": null,
                    "client_cert": null,
                    "client_key": null,
                    "creates": null,
                    "dest": null,
                    "follow_redirects": "safe",
                    "force": false,
                    "force_basic_auth": true,
                    "group": null,
                    "headers": {
                        "Accept": "application/json",
                        "Content-Type": "application/json"
                    },
                    "http_agent": "ansible-httpget",
                    "method": "GET",
                    "mode": null,
                    "owner": null,
                    "password": "VALUE_SPECIFIED_IN_NO_LOG_PARAMETER",
                    "remote_src": false,
                    "removes": null,
                    "return_content": false,
                    "selevel": null,
                    "serole": null,
                    "setype": null,
                    "seuser": null,
                    "src": null,
                    "status_code": [
                        200
                    ],
                    "timeout": 30,
                    "unix_socket": null,
                    "unredirected_headers": [],
                    "unsafe_writes": false,
                    "url": "https://manage.runcloud.io/api/v2/servers/IDRANDOM",
                    "url_password": "VALUE_SPECIFIED_IN_NO_LOG_PARAMETER",
                    "url_username": "apikey",
                    "use_gssapi": false,
                    "use_proxy": true,
                    "user": "apikey",
                    "validate_certs": true
                }
            },
            "item": "IDRANDOM",
            "json": {
                "agentVersion": "2.5.8-1+ubuntu16.04+2",
                "connected": true,
                "created_at": "2018-04-19 16:05:05",
                "id": 13430,
                "ipAddress": "1.1.1.1",
                "name": "Servername",
                "online": true,
                "os": "Ubuntu",
                "osVersion": "xenial",
                "phpCLIVersion": "php74rc",
                "provider": "Vultr",
                "securityUpdate": true,
                "softwareUpdate": true,
                "transferStatus": "AVAILABLE"
            },
            "msg": "OK (unknown bytes)",
            "nel": "{\"success_fraction\":0,\"report_to\":\"cf-nel\",\"max_age\":604800}",
            "redirected": false,
            "report_to": "{\"endpoints\":[{\"url\":\"https:\\/\\/a.nel.cloudflare.com\\/report\\/v3?s=lfVjvut37PXPVmmCPdsiNjd72K0z5Nq%2BZgKeKOeKRcM9k5eiBnwpdkbYz3erDLG85Yj10S6lA0FqXIKT0U7gt1zzo4OOk5d9TFUWzWhK4OBqJ7Ppn9WmBLx3ilfBzzqijrEQqw%3D%3D\"}],\"group\":\"cf-nel\",\"max_age\":604800}",
            "server": "cloudflare",
            "status": 200,
            "strict_transport_security": "max-age=31536000",
            "transfer_encoding": "chunked",
            "url": "https://manage.runcloud.io/api/v2/servers/IDRANDOM",
            "vary": "Accept-Encoding",
            "x_content_type_options": "nosniff",
            "x_frame_options": "SAMEORIGIN",
            "x_ratelimit_limit": "60",
            "x_ratelimit_remaining": "58",
            "x_xss_protection": "1; mode=block"
        }
    ]
}
**Show Name and IP...
  127.0.0.1 ok: {
    "changed": false,
    "msg": ""**
}

- Play recap -
  127.0.0.1                  : ok=5    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

So, What Am I doing wrong ?

I've tried to follow two articles about Json_query and JMESPath, however, maybe I am using the wrong syntax.

```
- name: Show Name and IP
          debug:
             msg: "{{ page.results | json_query(info) }}"
          vars: 
             info: "page.results[*].{Name: name, IP: IpAddress}"
```

URL:
https://www.middlewareinventory.com/blog/ansible_json_query/
https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/5/collections/community/general/docsite/filter_guide_selecting_json_data.html

Thanks!

Comment: `page.results` is already what you feed to the `json_query` filter, so you don't have that structure in the JSON you pass to JMESPath anymore, remove that out of your query (your variable `info`): `info: "[*].{Name: name, IP: IpAddress}"`

Comment: Almost: the result was null for Name and IP. "msg": [{"IP": null,"Name": null},

Comment: `info: "[*].{Name: json.name, IP: json.ipAddress}"`, from what I see in your output.

Answer (score 0):

Solved!! Thanks for your attention!

Solution:

```
- name: Show Name and IP
  debug:
     msg: "{{ page.results | json_query(info) }}"
  vars: 
     info: "[*].{Name: json.name, IP: json.ipAddress}"
```